# citation management: recent experience

Tags: document-creation

Early reports about Mma's citation management with BibTeX databases were not very encouraging.  So up to now I've been working without any citation management.  I am now considering trying this Mma facility.  Can the citation management facility be considered mature enough for serious use at this point?

If so, I must be doing something badly wrong: I cannot get Mma to even load a BibTeX database.  (Mma 11, Win 10)  It just spins its wheels with a "Loading" message and spits out errors.

Citation management is crucial for document production.  Has Wolfram made any real progress on this?

Comment: On Mac, it's still broken, no significant change from my answer to [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15872/245). Can't say anything about Windows versions, but from my perspective there is no there there. I'd guess you're not doing anything wrong at all, except for considering Mma for this task (sadly).