# Where is the "Insert > Citation> Bibliographical Reference" Command?

Tags: version-9, citation-management

I don't have the command for inserting citations described in the documentation:  "Insert > Citation> Bibliographical Reference" is not present in my menus:

[image]

That's the entire contents of my "Citation" menu: no "Bibliographical Reference" item anywhere to be seen.

How do I restore this item to my menus? What could I have done that would have removed it?

Comment: FWIW: 9.0.1 (the problem was there in 9.0.0 also) and OS X 10.8.2.

Comment: I'm running Mathematica 9.0 under windows 7 64-bit and that command IS present.  This must be an operating system thing...

Comment: @ToddAllen: I fear it may be a "my machine" thing. It's clearly suppose to be there. It was there the first few times I used 9.0, but I haven't seen it since. And the update to 9.0.1 has made no difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're on Mac, then the documentation is unfortunately deceiving you. Here is a thread I found on [MathGroup](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/vN5Ix7deOJI/ZaMryEgKBrAJ) that says what I also found: there's no `BibTeX` support on Mac OS X, and this fact is intentionally omitted from the docs. I say "intentionally" because clearly the above thread indicates that they are aware of the mismatch between their docs and reality.

I was unable to find a way to load `.bib` files in *Mathematica*. I also use `BibDesk` which I consider a great substitute for EndNote. So the conclusion: use another editor for publication quality work.

Comment: That could explain it. Though it would not explain why Wolfram's "Premier" (so called) "support" does not know about it. I've exchanged half a dozen e-mails with them about this, and all I get is mechanical responses that refer me to the documentation (the reading and re-reading of which is of course the initial source of my awareness of the feature), without a hint that it might not be supported on OS X. Also: it was present ([though it didn't work](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15471/37)) for a bit.

Comment: Confirmed! Though it tool Wolfram's "Premier" "support" 3 and a half months to finally answer my question (after many wrong and contradictory responses). Here's what I finally got: **"It's only presently supported under Windows."**

Comment: That's an uncommonly long delay for a response. Maybe this means their lawyers got involved... so I better watch what I write...

Comment: In my experience, it's not a long time for a *correct* response. After more than 4 months, I'm still waiting for answers to several other simple questions. (But that's a discussion for another place.)

Comment: There also is no support on Linux.

Comment: that's a bit of a snag, it's 2022 and still nothing?

Comment: @Hirek Indeed - I also checked the most recent templates of the "Mathematica Journal" and see no way to enter references other than manually.