# Alternative for citation management in Mathematica 9 for Mac

Tags: citation-management

I have just read that Mathematica 9 for Mac does not support Citation Management.

Any ideas of a poor's man replacement so I can still use Mathematica on Mac for editing? I mean, have someone written a script to "import" a .bib into a notebook or something like that?

I took the time to put all my references in a .bib file. I also imported them into EndNote. If this is of any help...

regards,
Mr. Disappointed

Comment: You've probably seen this: [Where is the “Insert > Citation> Bibliographical Reference” Command?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18835/245). I recommend using [LyX](http://www.lyx.org) if you need BibTeX integration and want excellent math typesetting.

Comment: David Park's *Presentations* add-on (http://home.comcast.net/~djmpark/DrawGraphicsPage.html) includes a References sub-package that allows you to  maintain a list of reference records for a notebook, display them, and insert specific references into text. It does *not* use `.bib` files or similar TeX-type files, nor is it a full-fledged references system.