# citation insertion from bibtex file does not seem to work

Tags: citation-management

When I try to insert a citation in a text cell using the right click citation/insert bibliographic reference, and then choose the Bibtex option, I get the complaining window shown.  This happens no matter what bibtex file I use.
What to do?  Does anyone else have success with citation insertion using bibtex?  If so, can you provide a example?
[image: citation insertion from bibtex file: failure notification]

Comment: There has already been a discussion few years ago on this subject. Unfortunately I cannot give any reference. As much as I remember, the outcome was that this feature does not work. So, your observation states that it still does not work.

Comment: Furthering Alexei's comment, this has been discussed [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15471/how-do-i-start-a-reference-system). I personally have experienced the same behavior as Peter with Mathematica 10. The discussion in the link seems to refer to Mathematica 8 and 9.

Comment: Related: [Where is the “Insert > Citation> Bibliographical Reference” Command?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18835/245)

Comment: I have had success using a literature database created by JabRef (http://jabref.sourceforge.net/), which uses BibTex. I've been able to get Mathematica V8, 9 & 10 to work with it, under Windows.  Even so, the current citation management of Mathematica is very frail and prone to crashing.

Comment: Five years later, Mathematica 12.1 still produces the same error!

Comment: @divenex Now it's turn for 13.0.